# Fixing graphs with large y scale range. Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to make several plots, but the problem I'm facing is that most of these plots have a period where they spike up in value, and that masks the actual data I'm interested in. I don't think Limiting the Y-axis range will work since the Y-axis scale changes for different plots.

Here is an example of my problem

[image]

I want to remove all those peaks, because it they might be overshadowing something interesting with the plot.

Here is the code I used to plot generate this figure:

```
    fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharex = False,  figsize =(15,15))


    ax1.plot(Epoch[0], plotdata[0])
    ax1.set_ylabel(label, fontsize = 20)
    ax1.tick_params(axis = 'both',which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
    ax1.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out',width=2)
    ax1.set_xlim([start1, stop1])
    nbins = 5
    ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))


    ax2.plot(Epoch[1],plotdata[1])
    ax2.set_ylabel(label, fontsize = 20)
    ax2.set_xlim([start2, stop2])
    ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both',which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
    ax2.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out',width=2)


    ax3.plot(Epoch[2], plotdata[2])
    ax3.set_ylabel(label, fontsize =20)
    ax3.set_xlim([start3, stop3])
    ax3.tick_params(axis = 'both',which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
    ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
    ax3.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out',width=2)

    ax4.plot(Epoch[3], plotdata[3])
    ax4.set_ylabel(label, fontsize =20)
    ax4.set_xlim([start4, stop4])
    ax4.tick_params(axis = 'both',which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
    ax4.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
    ax4.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out',width=2)
```

Comment: this seems like a data filtering issue, not a plotting issue. I would look `numpy.ma.masked_greater` and `numpy.where`

Answer (score 1):

Make the y-axis a log scale. This will make rest of plot stand out more.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work well. For some reason, only the peaks show up in the graph. I have done it manually for all the graphs though. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, try a log scale with

`plt.semilogy()`